# Jest UI React js components - unit tests

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am pretty new to React and Jest unit test framework. I have my component and trying to write few unit test cases , tried few ways and unable to proceed further. Here is my code and test case. Can anyone guide /suggest the best approaches please.
Non of the tests work and 
Thanks

React UI component Header

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navbar, NavbarBrand } from 'reactstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';


const Header = ({children}) =>
    <Navbar light className="sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-toggleable-sm bg-white border-bottom">
        <NavbarBrand tag={Link} to="/">Abc: Customer Portal</NavbarBrand>
        <div className="d-flex w-100 justify-content-end">
            {children}
        </div>
    </Navbar>

export default Header
```

Tests - non of them pass, could anyone please guide me in the right direction.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Navbar, NavbarBrand } from 'reactstrap';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { render, unmountComponentAtNode, ReactDOM } from "react-dom";
import { act } from "react-dom/test-utils";
import GlobalSettings from './../features/Header/GlobalSettings';
import UserDisplayName from './../features/Header/UserDisplayName';
import Header from './../features/Header/';

let container = null;
beforeEach(() => {
    // setup a DOM element as a render target
    container = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(container);
});

afterEach(() => {
    // cleanup on exiting
    unmountComponentAtNode(container);
    container.remove();
    container = null;
});

test('test Header component', () => {
    //const nav = document.createElement('Navbar');
    ReactDOM.render(<Header>
        <Link to="/">Damage Matrix: Customer Portal</Link>
                    </Header>, Navbar);
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(nav);
});


test('test Header', () => {
    act(() => {
        render(<Header />, container);
    });
    expect(container.appendChild).toBe("Hello");

    act(() => {
        render(<Header children="GlobalSettings" />, container);
    });
    expect(container.textContent).toBe("GlobalSettings");

});

test('renders correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(
        <Header />
    ).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: 1 test case it errors as :  TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined    
                                                                                                                            2 and 3 test case it errors as : Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>